# Cannot find entry while adding project to assembly deploy

Tags: eclipse, deployment

I have three projects in my workspace:

- xand-cc-conduct-common (1)
- xand-cc-conduct-client (2)
- xand-cc-conduct-client-webapp (3)

While deploying the project (3) other two (1), (2) must be in WEB-INF/lib as jar files.

So, I go to Project properties --> Deployment assembly, then I add project (1) by pressing Add... --> Project and selecting the project.

When I do that a message "Cannot find entry: "xand-cc-conduct-common"" appears.

The .metadata .log file is empty.

Can somebody help, please?

The eclipse version is Helios.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "xand-cc-conduct-common" in Manifest Entries tab? (Project properties-->Deployment assembly-->Manifest Entries) If no try to add this jar.